# Parallel speakers sound bad, but serials are fine

Tags: audio, speakers, distortion

I have made a simple speaker circuit. It sounds (at least to me) surprisingly good (though an audiophile would probably scream out loud and run away). I have currently run across a problem.

To increase the volume and increase the audio quality (make speakers *share* the burden) I have tried different configurations for four speakers, paralleling them all, serialing them, and parallel two serialed by the other two. Adding speakers in serial only has good effect to the audio quality, but as soon as I use any one of them in *parallel* the audio quality gets notably noisier/distorted. I don't really understand why. What is going on? I want to be able to parallel speakers because serialing them is good for audio quality, but it does decrease the volume, and that is a problem, especially if want to use even more speakers.

A "simple" fix would be to increase the power supply so I can drive them with higher voltages, but I am a little scared of that :P and it would also put more pressure on the involved components. Using a rail-to-rail op-amp could perhaps improve the situation a little, but there will still a voltage loss across the push-pull [BJTs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipolar_junction_transistor) (I guess), and I don't have any suitable rail-to-rail op-amps available.

It's annoying that it *almost* works. I don't need the best sound quality or volume, but only something that is somewhat acceptable.

[image: Serialed]

[image: Parallelled]

- [Link to a somewhat inaccurate simulation of my circuit](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%201%200.000005%202.803162489452614%2062%205%2043%0Av%2096%20320%2096%2048%200%200%2040%205%200%200%200.5%0Ax%20107%20171%20181%20174%200%2015%205V%20wallwart%0Ax%20109%20386%20183%20389%200%2015%205V%20wallwart%0Av%2096%20480%2096%20320%200%200%2040%205%200%200%200.5%0Aw%2096%2048%20208%2048%200%0Aa%20464%20160%20544%20160%200%205%20-5%201000000%0Ar%20208%2048%20208%20208%200%2030000%0Aw%2096%20320%20208%20320%200%0Ar%20208%20320%20208%20208%200%2010000%0Aw%20208%20208%20464%20208%200%0Ax%20222%20201%20259%20204%200%2015%201.25V%0AR%20320%20144%20288%20144%200%201%20200%202.5%202.5%200%200.5%0Ax%20251%20106%20329%20109%200%2015%200V-5V%20PWM%0Aw%20464%20144%20464%2096%200%0Aw%20544%20160%20544%2096%200%0Ar%20544%2096%20464%2096%200%2010000%0Aw%20544%20160%20576%20160%200%0Ax%20476%20215%20554%20236%200%2015%20level%20shifting%5Cnopamp%0At%20720%20144%20752%20144%200%201%20-1.4267331588818561%200.7225434365138246%20100%0At%20720%20208%20752%20208%200%20-1%208.573266841118144%200.7225434365138246%20100%0Aw%20752%20160%20752%20176%200%0Aw%20752%20192%20752%20176%200%0Aw%20752%20176%20800%20176%200%0Aw%20720%20144%20720%20176%200%0Aw%20720%20208%20720%20176%200%0Aa%20608%20176%20688%20176%201%205%20-5%201000000%0Aw%20208%20320%20400%20320%200%0Ar%20608%20240%20688%20240%200%2010000%0Aw%20576%20160%20608%20160%200%0Ar%20608%20240%20608%20320%200%205000%0Aw%20688%20176%20688%20240%200%0Aw%20608%20192%20608%20240%200%0Aw%20688%20176%20720%20176%200%0Ag%2032%20320%2032%20368%200%0Aw%2032%20320%2096%20320%200%0Ar%20400%20144%20464%20144%200%2010000%0Ac%20400%20144%20400%20320%200%200.000002%201.308851497798613%0Aw%20400%20320%20608%20320%200%0Aw%20464%20208%20464%20176%200%0Ar%20320%20144%20400%20144%200%200.1%0Aw%20208%2048%20752%2048%200%0Aw%20752%2048%20752%2096%200%0Aw%20752%2096%20752%20128%200%0Aw%2096%20480%20752%20480%200%0Aw%20752%20480%20752%20224%200%0Ar%20800%20176%20864%20176%200%208%0Aw%20608%20320%20864%20320%200%0Aw%20864%20320%20864%20176%200%0Ao%2016%2064%200%20291%204.374501449566024%209.765625e-105%200%20-1%0Ao%2032%2064%200%20290%2020%200.003125%201%20-1%0A)

**Additional information:**

- The speakers are of two different types, but even if I just parallel only two identical speakers do the noise/distortion issue come up (and leave the other two unconnected).
- It is probably not relevant, but my dual supply consists of two 5 V wall warts.
- The op-amp I am using is the quad op-amp **[LM324AN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_LM-series_integrated_circuits#Operational_amplifiers)**. It's not rail-to-rail.
- A 100 (to about 220) ohm resistor between the immediate output of the right op-amp and ground decreases the noise in all configurations. I don't know why; I just stumbled across this when I connected a cable incorrectly :p
- And BTW: I don't think the noise/distortion issue comes from paralleling speakers drawing too much current, because the volume has no/small effect on it. It it was a current supply issue then a higher volume would (I think) very much worsen it.
- The purpose of the first op-amp is to center the 0 V to 5 V input around GND i.e. the output from the fist op-amp is -2.5 V to +2.5 V.
- Both op-amps are supplied from the +5 V -5 V rails. That is unfortunately not showing up in the schematic though.

**Some more research**

Okey. So I did put my oscilloscope to action and probed the voltage before the speakers (after the push-pull).

This is how it looks like with one speaker (and yes there is a lot of >20 kHz noise):

[image: One speaker!]

This is how it looks with two identical speakers in parallel under otherwise the same circumstances. The voltage did actually not decrease, but there is this strange thing at the bottom which must be the noise that I hear:

[image: Two speakers in parallel]

On the following image it is even more noticeable!:

[image]

BTW, the second trace is just a marker. It is not showing ground and ground is approximately in the middle of the waveform.

**Oh! I am terribly sorry the schematic was wrong on one crucial point. I did have the feedback after the push-pulls! Like this:**

[image: This time correct]

================================

**Some more research and the solution**

================================

First an image of the audio signal on trace1 and GND on trace2 as requested. It does not seem to be very DC biased:

[image]

But still it was interesting to take a look at how the rails looked when the audio was noisy. This is picture of the positive rail and GND. It looks noisy, and it gets worse with higher volume:

[image: Positive rail]

The negative rail is at the *same* volume and is notably worse than the positive rail, at least to my eyes (my slow camera blurs!):

[image: Negative rail]

The first thing I attempted was adding a 1 µF capacitor between op-amp output and ground, and I was quite surprised to hear that **the noise disappeared**!!

This is how the negative rail looks like at the same volume, but with the added 1 µF capacitor:

[image: Negative rail after added capacitor]

So that simple 1 µF capacitor solved my issue! Thanks to everybody, it would have taken MUCH longer for me to solve this without your help :)

This is how a sinus wave looks after the capacitor was added. Mmm, I can stare at that all day long...:

[image: Crisp sine curve mmm]

**Update 2016-03-09**

I replaced the *opamp level shifter* with a *1uF AC coupling film capacitor* and a 10k ohm resistor to GND after it. I did not really notice any improvements to the sound quality BUT I did notice that the biasing with a capacitor instead of the opamp level shifter is more *safe*. With the opamp level shifter if it, for whatever reason, would place the signal either too high or too low then the NPN or PNP part of the push-pull output stage would have to carry a heavier load resulting in heating up (not good!). So, I will keep the AC coupling capacitor.

I also added an inductor to filter out the PWM frequencies (~0.3mF), that very much improved the appearance of the sine curve.

Though, even with these two improvements the original issue still arise if I remove the 0.22uF cap between the opamp output pin and GND. Here under are images showing a 440Hz sine-wave with and without that 0.22uF cap.

[image]

Comment: Without measurements, who can tell? But at a wild guess, the lower load impedance of parallel speakers is clipping (distorting) due to limited output current from the amp. Increasing the *current* (not volltage) rating of the wall warts may help, but you may also need to upgrade the output transistors (and their driver stage) to benefit from it. If you can measure the supply volts and it sags when loud and distorted, this is the problem.

Comment: @BrianDrummond Actually, since OP stated that the distortion when parallelling didn't occur when serialing the speakers, we can be 99.8% sure it's aproblem of the speakers overrunning the amplifier damping factor by presenting a lower load impedance than the amp can effectively drive. - It's a popular problem for 'budding audiophiles' to experience (aka: "been there, bought the T-shirt). ;)

Comment: @RobhercKV5ROB very good point, there is more than one consequence of the lower load impedance.

Comment: Thanks to all of you! "99.8% sure". I am quite surprised by that estimation, but I will test the voltages and see if the noise/distortion coexists with a voltage drop. If that is the case the all of you three are right I guess.

Comment: @taz0k Please read the top half (everything above the edit) of my answer, and the wikipedia article I linked there. The problem with your speakers overrunning the amplifier's damping factor is with the *output voltage* sagging, not the power supply voltage. Unfortunately, with audio output there's no way to measure this with a multimeter. In order to "see" it, you would need an oscilliscope & a "trained eye" (or at least a copy of the input signal right next to the output signal for comparison) to confirm it any more than your ears already have.

Comment: Can we see the 'scope outputs with the second trace coming from your circuit ground, please? It might help explain that *severe* sagging if we can see the *actual* ground's behavior next to that.

Comment: Also, unrelated to your asked question, try adding a ~15-20KHz Low-Pass Filter to that PWM input to reduce some of that nasty output noise ;) - - http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/74014/low-pass-sallen-key-with-variable-cut-off-frequency

Comment: @RobhercKV5ROB I am not sure exactly what you mean? You mean so you can see the ground? I only (unfortunately) have one probe but the second trace is set to GND on the scope (which is connected to the circuit ground) and is shifted down with the vertical knob, so I think it should show ground but just with a DC bias.

Comment: Ok, then at least the *shape* of the waveform is normalized to your signal gnd...even if the/any measured DC offset can't be seen (would be preferable to see the *actual* dc offset too, though).

Comment: From the traces shown, it **really** looks like your circuit is operating with a few volts of dc output bias, especially when you look at the bottom scope output where the 'smears' at the bottom of the waveform peak nearly equidistant from the gnd trace to the +V peaks.

Comment: Again, GET RID OF THE LEVEL SHIFTING OPAMP.  A passive high pass filter will do a better job, doesn't rely on you thinking you know the DC offset and nulling it out, and won't be susceptible to feeback thru the power supply like your circuit is.

Comment: I don't know what you actually did, but I never said to put any cap between the opamp output and either rail.  That would be bad.  I did mention a 1 uF cap as part of a input high pass filter.  Otherwise, I said to put caps across each supply, and a bypass cap across the supply pins of the opamp.

Comment: @OlinLathrop I think he effectively (accidentally) added high-pass to rail & effectively grounded out most of his HF PWM noise to the rails (of course, only *after* amplifying it through the whole circuit).

Comment: That's hilarious. I misread the schematic. It was C2 I was looking at and now I see it's from +5V to -5V and not from +5V to the output of the opamp. Rob is probably correct.

Comment: So now I disconnected that 1uF cap at the opamp output from +5V an connected it instead to ground, that probably makes more sense.

Comment: @taz0k in Olin's schematic, that was functioning as a decoupling cap across the opamp's supplies...helps smooth supply to the opamp to counteract trace inductance on the power rails. In order to more effectively low-pass the HF noise from your PWM input, try adding a 1mH inductor between R2 & opAmp, then a 47nF cap parallel to R2.

Comment: No, what I drew makes more sense.  I don't get it.  I've given you a complete schematic, but you seem to have tried everything except that.  First you put C2 between +5V and the opamp output, then between +5V and ground.  What is so hard about doing what I suggested?  It also seems you still have that stupid level shifter in there, which provides the feedback path thru +5V for the whole amp to oscillate.  Why ask for advice if you're not going to at least try it?

Comment: @OlinLathrop Putting C2 there was a mistake, I read the schematic incorrectly. Clumsiness. But adding the cap there improved the sound quality so it will stay until I notice that I dont need it. I lowered it's value to 0.22uF, that still removes much noise. I just added a 1uF cap, now at the right place over the rails by the opamp. I did not notice any difference. Then I added C3 & C4. I did not have 470uF so I tried 200uF. That improved that stability of the rails slightly. Then I tried to find some larger caps. Now I have 3.3mF from + to GND and 1mF from the - to GND, and that's much better.

Comment: The cap between the opamp output and ground is really a bad thing.  I understand why it *appears* to fix the immediate obvious symptom, but it shouldn't be there and the problems should be fixed the right way.  Now that you have large caps on each supply and a bypass cap on the opamp power, get rid of the cap on the opamp output.  But, you need to get rid of the level shifting circuit and replace it with a capacitor and resistor as I said.  *That* will be what will make the whole amp more stable by eliminating the feeback from output to input thru the +5V supply.

Comment: @OlinLathrop Before I remove the level shifter I wanted to make some measurements and understand why it would cause problems. I am not sure why it would. I have seen, as you and others have pointed out and on my scope, that I am upsetting the rails at high volumes (less after adding C3 and C4). Is the theory that the upset rail would upset my voltage divider before the level shifter? After upgrading with a 440uF to GND from divider output made and it "only" changes +-4mV at full volume, i.e. less than a percent of the voltage divider output. Next thing I do is to replace it with a cap, finally

Comment: @taz0k Looking at your newest 'scope pics, I think you might be seeing some power supply noise on the volume 30 w/o output->gnd cap trace. This is likely from your - rail supply "running low" at higher volume, the imbalance of your supply resevoir caps, or from parasitkcs on your reserve/decoupling caps. It is best to use ceramic, thin-film, or mica caps for all your decoupling, and often suggestable to place one near your (usually electrolytic, or Al-poly) reserve caps. In either case, the lower parasitic resistance/inductance capacitors help filter hf noises more effectively.

Comment: At the very least, please be sure to use at minimum a ceramic cap for C1 and C2 (as labeled in Olin's diagram)

Comment: @RobhercKV5ROB Oh.. so C2 should have been a ceramic cap.... doh, I used an electrolytic. I will try to find something better and then see if that helps.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your amplifier has a fixed output impedance and finite voltage swing.  To get the most power out of it, the load impedance has to match the output impedance.   Two speakers in parallel have half the impedance of one speaker.  This is apparently too low for your amp to drive properly.

Probably your "wallwart" supplies are collapsing under the heavy drain of two speakers in parallel.  The lower supply voltage makes the 1.5 V or so deadband in your output a larger fraction of the overall, significantly increasing distortion.  You don't say what kind of opamps you are using, other than they are not rail to rail.  The supply voltage may be collapsing to the point where there is little active region left between the deadband in the output and the output range of the final opamp.

In addition, parts of your circuit don't make sense and could rather easily be replaced by a better design:

You have symmetric ± supplies.  That's good. So why why why are you level shifting the input away from ground-centered?

Upon closer inspection, it seems you are level shifting to compensate for the input signal being centered around 2.5 V.  This is just plain silly.

You can't hear DC.  Even "HiFi" audio only goes down to 20 Hz.  The obvious way to deal with input DC offsets is to AC couple the signal.  Get rid of all the nonsense to the left of the positive input of the second opamp.  Replace it with a 1 µF cap in series followed by a 10 kΩ resistor to ground.

You seem to be willing to live with the deadband in the dual emitter follower output stage, but at least include it in the feedback loop so that the opamp can try to compensate for it.  All this requires is to connect the 10 kΩ (Argh, no component designators) feedback resistor to the output of the whole amp instead of the output of the opamp.

Here is your basic circuit with the obvious points mentioned above fixed:

[image]

Note that this is both simpler and will work better.

There are ways to significantly reduce the final stage deadband.  Two diodes is a very common approach.

What I usually do is use a couple more transistors in the output stage to give it a gain of 2.  The previous stage then only has to drive to ± half the supply range.  That gets around needing a rail to rail opamp, which generally aren't available at the ±12 V or more you want to run them at.

### Added in response to scope traces

You have even more problems than you realize.

Your circuit is oscillating under load, almost certainly by feeding back thru the power supplies.  I should have explicitly mentioned this, but that's what C3 and C4 in my circuit are intended to prevent.  Try the circuit I posted.  It uses mostly the same parts but should perform better.

You can also see evidence of the output stage deadband on the scope trace.  Again, including the output stage in the feedback look will help with this, although it won't fix it.

I now see the opamp is a LM324.  That's not a good choice for audio.  I'd use a TL07x with ±12 V supplies at least.  That will probably mean beefier output transistors, possibly with heat sinks.

Once you get this working, I can show you how to get more voltage swing and less deadband from the output stage, but one thing at a time.  That would be for a new question anyway.

Comment: All good points, but I think you might have missed the OP's mention that they're using **mismatched** speakers, in addition to the poor amp design, mismatched parallel loads always == trouble ;)

Comment: @Rob: Mismatched is definitely bad, but he also said this problem is observed with the same speakers in parallel.  In any case, all I said above still applies.  I should have mentioned that mismatched speakers are bad, but you've already done that.

Comment: Thanks! Oh, that was very clumsy of me. The feedback actually is taken from after the push-pulls (directly before the speaker(s)). I don't understand why my level shifting would be silly. I need to center it around ground somehow I guess? The opamp will add noise and take up space (well now I am using a quad opamp so it won't not really space). I tried to use a AC coupling capacitor but the audio quality decreased (perhaps because of low quality caps?) perhaps because a an RC filter has a (I assume) slower response time...
I'll read through your answer again and see what I an/will do :)

Comment: @taz0k As an aside (material for a new question), why are you using push-pull tl drive one terminal of the speaker +/-5V from gnd, rather than connecting to both terminals of the sleaker with a balanced output stage for +/- 10V pushed/pulled through the speakers? Assuming adequate supply current availability, this effectively doubles (or better, re: deadband) your dynamic range).

Comment: @taz: Passive high pass filtering at the front of a audio amp is effective and how it's normally done.  Active level shifting only subtracts off a specific DC level, so isn't as good and is more complicated.  C1 in my circuit must be a bipolar cap.  If you use a ceramic, make sure it's rated for significantly more than the voltage you will be using.  1 uF 20 V should be fine.  That's because some ceramics are quite non-linear at near the full voltage.  There are better choices than ceramic, but that will do for now and let you get on to the real problems.

Comment: Thanks Olin. I assume that it is because I have been using eletrolytics (back-to-back) that I have a bad experience of caps.

@RobhercKV5ROB Hm that is a good idea! The only reason is that it is more complicated really. Since what you propose is more effective and I wouldn't have to increase the voltage, implementing it is something I should do.

Comment: So, the opamp level shifter is now gone. I am now convinced that a AC coupling capacitor is better because of the easy "automatic centering" of the signal. It makes it easier for the output stage transistors that now heat up less because of the better/more reliable centering of the signal.

Answer (score 4):

- *And btw. I don't think the noise/distortion issue comes from paralleling speakers drawing too much current because the volume has no/small effect on it. It it was a current supply issue then a higher volume would (I think) very much worsen it.*

I like that you applied some good electrical troubleshooting technique/logic here. Unfortunately, however, your logic missed a salient point.

When driving dynamic audio transducers (speakers with magnets & voice coils), your amplifier needs to have a ***lower*** source impedance than the load it is driving.

The amount that the amplifier's source impedance reaches *below* the load impedance of the speakers is called the "[damping factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damping_factor)" in the pro audio world in reference to it relating to the amplifier's ability to drive the speaker with accuracy while the extra available current (and directly related ability to fight voltage "sags") fights (dampens) the effects of moving air & external vibrations, etc. trying to distort the motion of the voice coil.

In order to effectively run 4 mismatched speakers from your output without frying any speakers & without causing bad distortion, you'll really need to add 3 more final output staves in parallel to the one you have now. Then, you can connect each speaker to its own output. This will achieve the higer volume/volt capability you wanted to get by paralleling the speakers, while avoiding blowing your amp by drawing too much current, and blowing the speaker with the lowest impedance because most of the power would flow through it if the speakers were all parallelled on one channel.

`- - - - - - - - - - Added Schematic - - - - - - - - - -`

Here's a schematic of a circuit, using most of your existing components, combining low-pass/high-pass on the audio input to get rid of the DC offset & the PWM ultrasonic noise. Also, it includes parallel speaker drive outputs, along with Olin's decoupling capacitors between power supplies & gnd, as well as decoupling the LM324AN.

[image: circuit schematic]

Note: It *would definitely be better* to drive each push/pull unit from a separate opamp output, with its own feedback loop, but that would require 2 more LM324ANs (wire use the feed from 1OUT to run all 4 "final out" sections, with each "final out" wired like OpAmps 3 & 4 to 1 speaker per OpAmp pair)

Comment: Thanks!.

Just a comment on your second point. No, the opamps are supplied from +5V and -5V (not showed in schematic though), and the first opamp level shifts the 0V to 5V input to -2.5V to +2.5V, I have confirmed that with my oscilloscope.

Comment: @taz0k ok, then it's just that your schematics are wrong then, because they show everything except for the one NPN "final output" transistor as being grounded between the 2 supplies (might be part of why you found the simulation to be "somewhat inaccurate").

Comment: Regarding your first point: I have seen a capacitor added like that on other audio circuits. I also thought that I should add one (so that current would not "theoretically" go to infinity in the speaker, and/or make the speaker "cone" to too much to one or the other direction). But unfortunately adding a capacitor reduces that quality of the sound. I have tested electrolytic ones with values of about 1(or was it 10...) to 220uF. Maybe I should test an even higher value...

Comment: Thanks, you are right that I can and should test to have (at least) two (or better four) opamps with push-pull bjts, instead of (as I have now) only one.

Comment: @taz0k Not to yell, but this point ks *incresibly* important: ***DO NOT EVER USE ELECTROLYTIC CAPS FOR COUPLING AC WAVEFORMS*** - - Electrolytic capacitors are intended to *always* be dc-biased in the dkrection they're labeled, and **they may explode** when thjs polarity is reversed. - - Try instead using a ceramic, mica, thin-film, or oil-and-paper cap. Getting one that's big enough for low impedance at audio frequencies isn't cneap, but neither is replacing blown-out equipment ;)

Comment: Hehe. Safety is important! I used electrolytics connected back-to-back, I read that that should make it tolerant in both directions, or is electrolytics still a no-no?

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with push-me-pull-you negating the reversed polarity on the electrolytics, but series-wiring any caps reduces their effective capacitance, and electrolytics have comparatively huge parasitics @ frequency, so even if they're "safer" that way, they'll still be the "noisiest" caps (besides lower quality electrolytics) that you could use.

Comment: I see. Thanks. I wish I had some non-electrolytic high valued caps.

Comment: @RobhercKV5ROB Of course you can use a polar capacitor for AC coupling, when you know the DC levels on each side. The capacitor only cares about the voltage _it_ sees across its pins, not the voltage relative to ground or any other point.

Comment: @pipe Uhmm, I'm thinking (hoping) that was a sarcastic post? Powering a speaker through a push-pull with an electrolytic coupling cap *by definition* both *pushes* and *pulls* current through the cap, so unless you create an intentional dc bias around the cap (possible, but a PITA), you have no way to keep the coupling cap from "seeing" a reverse-bias across its terminals & de-electrolyzing (with all the possible messiness .. including hugely non-linear response .. that entails).

Comment: Damping factor is an audio myth. What matters is having a low output impedance, period. It's always expressed as into 8 ohms, so all you are really being told is 8/ the output impedance of the amplifier.

Comment: @EJP we're not talking about factory-assembled amplifiers here, we're talkimg about hand-built equipment & *real* measurements, not factory fairytales, so please don't confuse the two.

Comment: Oh thanks! You really put effort into that! Awesome. I will take inspiration.

Comment: So one opamp is inverting and the other non-inverting. I don't recognize that appearance of the inverting opamp. Feedback to the 2IN+? Should it not be 2IN+ to ground, 2IN- to the audio input signal via a resistor, and 2IN- to Q3/Q4 "output" via another resistor?

Comment: @RobhercKV5ROB My reply to your comment was meant to highlight the specific sentence "DO NOT EVER USE ELECTROLYTIC CAPS FOR COUPLING AC WAVEFORMS" which is simply not true on its own. In a lot of circuits you know the relevant bias levels on each side of the cap, and thus it is not a problem. Because it's written in **bold**, it stands out, and someone might see that sentence and get the wrong impression.

Comment: @taz0k It doesn't make any difference. The important quantity is the output impedance, not the dubious quantity of 'damping factor'. If you think otherwise, please give your reasons. It's your assertion: support it.

Comment: I am still confused. I believe there is a problem there in the schematic. Hopefully I traced it correctly. Here is a link to a simulation. I have omitted the push-pulls for simplicity (should not make relevant difference for what I want to show). circuit1 (to the left) is from your schematic, the waveform is distorted. circuit2 is only the "negative-side" opamp in action, we see that it flips from rail to rail like a squarewave. circuit3 is what I imagine to be correct. I imagine that feedback to the positive input of the opamp is not how to do it
Link to simulation: http://tinyurl.com/jb39qbu

Comment: @EJP "Damping Factor," as a *real* measurement, is simply load impedance/zource impedznce. We call it by that name for the ability of the source to overcome fluctuations in the load, and because it's easier to use 2 words to describe a measurement than it is to use 10. In the end, you are the one who wanted to start arguing, so it's your counter-intuitive assertion that there's no benefit to having a source impedance that's lower than the load impedance (damping factor >1) in order to overcome voltage-collapse of the source under load fluctuations.

Comment: @taz0k I'm sorry, I can't see enough of your sim on my phone to comment on it, but you're right in that I messed up that schematic. I built the 2 sides as "mirror images" & forgot that I was swapping negative feedback for positive feedback in the process...will update the schematic.

Comment: There are many, many problems with your schematic. Not only is the feedback around the opamps incorrect, but the input filter is not right, either. If L1 is supposed to be part of a low-pass filter, it's in the wrong place. And you only have feedback around one set of output transistors. Since we know that the loads are mismatched, you can't assume that all of the output stages can be driven identically.

Comment: Furthermore, you are still wrong about using polarized capacitors for AC coupling. You can have *current* flowing in both directions through a capacitor while still maintaining a definite DC *voltage* bias across it.

Comment: @DaveTweed Yes, I did mention (though maybe not with enough emphasis) that it would "be better" to have separate OpAmps & feedback for each speaker; we are in agreement there. As for the polarized capacitor thing, unfortunately we can't edit comments here, but my *intent* was that polarized caps are generally unsafe, or at least very much "not recommended" for between-stage signal couplig caps. I understand that they're usable for storage/reserve/decoupling/bypass caps where a constant/predictable DC bias is desirable/maintained across the capacitor.

Comment: Also, can you expound more on your statement abou5 L1 being placed incorrectly for a low-pass filter to remove the hf noise from the PWM input signal? I won't claim I can't have made a mistake there, but if I did, I'm not seeing it yet.

Comment: @taz0k Schematic updated & I deleted a couple of comments where I made mis-statements.

Comment: You have L1 directly feeding the high-impedance input of an opamp. Essentially zero current will be flowing through it, so its impedance will not have the effect you think. Also, your power supply decoupling caps are completely wrong. You have them in series with the ground leads!

Comment: @DaveTweed Agreed on the inductor, good point & thanks for pointing that out. On the decoupling caps, yep, I just added those wrong...completely wrong :(

Comment: Sorry about the low-pass error; comes from my being used to working with my preferred BJT-based amplifier stages, I sometimes forget about the high input impedance of op amps & FETs affecting my filters.

Comment: Just a word of advice. You generally seem to know what you're talking about, but your answers and your comments tend to be riddled with both typographical and technical errors like these. If you want to be taken seriously as an engineering resource, I would recommend that you spend a little more time proofreading and verifying what you write.

Comment: @RobhercKV5ROB Thanks! An inductor sure helped filter away the PWM frequencies!